# Why are all ports published by default with this Docker image

Tags: docker, port, fedora

Is there any inconspicuous configuration that would cause all ports to be published (accessible both in and outside docker containers)? The contain was run the image w/o any options, straight up like:

```
docker run -it xxx/xxx /bin/bash
```

Here's the inspect output (note that "PublishAllPorts" is set to false with only a few ports explicitly exposed):

```
 {
    "Id": "c0170d0dfde1a92550e4f3ac999cd13c9711f3b15493325d85a4b9c9542f5d01",
    "Created": "2016-12-02T05:19:27.91485137Z",
    "Path": "/bin/bash",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 26493,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2016-12-05T14:44:38.270973904Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2016-12-05T14:43:57.974501757Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:2b6dff71e5b964409749dacabe5653d57879b860bfbddf37bb40a51c3d3c5778",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c0170d0dfde1a92550e4f3ac999cd13c9711f3b15493325d85a4b9c9542f5d01/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c0170d0dfde1a92550e4f3ac999cd13c9711f3b15493325d85a4b9c9542f5d01/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c0170d0dfde1a92550e4f3ac999cd13c9711f3b15493325d85a4b9c9542f5d01/hosts",
    "LogPath": "",
    "Name": "/pedantic_perlman",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "devicemapper",
    "MountLabel": "system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0:c570,c970",
    "ProcessLabel": "system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0:c570,c970",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "journald",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {},
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": 0,
        "Ulimits": null
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "devicemapper",
        "Data": {
            "DeviceId": "38",
            "DeviceName": "docker-253:0-1970585-466a43a88fda2e37aa154f06eaf6dcdc1c7a68890be72471ded27e3e45f0b960",
            "DeviceSize": "10737418240"
        }
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "c0170d0dfde1",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": true,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "11000/tcp": {},
            "11443/tcp": {},
            "16000/tcp": {},
            "16001/tcp": {},
            "19888/tcp": {},
            "2181/tcp": {},
            "22/tcp": {},
            "60010/tcp": {},
            "7077/tcp": {},
            "8020/tcp": {},
            "8042/tcp": {},
            "8080/tcp": {},
            "8088/tcp": {},
            "8888/tcp": {},
            "8983/tcp": {},
            "9090/tcp": {},
            "9092/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "StdinOnce": true,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "TERM=xterm"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/bash"
        ],
        "Image": "docker.io/caioquirino/docker-cloudera-quickstart",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "e33871c583ead85bb1d5c68160f19fd67007e3f0fd18acaf92706d88e941d6a3",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "11000/tcp": null,
            "11443/tcp": null,
            "16000/tcp": null,
            "16001/tcp": null,
            "19888/tcp": null,
            "2181/tcp": null,
            "22/tcp": null,
            "60010/tcp": null,
            "7077/tcp": null,
            "8020/tcp": null,
            "8042/tcp": null,
            "8080/tcp": null,
            "8088/tcp": null,
            "8888/tcp": null,
            "8983/tcp": null,
            "9090/tcp": null,
            "9092/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/e33871c583ea",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "dfb52838892c31a3428efd6d0996b6f9ccbe2f9edc71a2a2e2cf0c08c622d538",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "17de08a7428d3243288647a88e991cdf8989b3c9aab17213a24acfbf396ded3a",
                "EndpointID": "dfb52838892c31a3428efd6d0996b6f9ccbe2f9edc71a2a2e2cf0c08c622d538",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But still I could still seem to hit any port:

```
 [root@localhost bryan]# curl 172.17.0.2:50070
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
```

Comment: What's the Dockerfile / image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exposed ports are defined in your Dockerfile and incorporated into the image configuration. They tell docker which ports the container listens on but does not publish them by default. You'd need to either publish specific ports with `-p` or publish all ports to random host ports with `-P`.

Depending on your linux iptables configuration, you'll be able to talk directly the the container interfaces/ports from the docker host, as your example shows. Unless you can reach the ports via your localhost interface, these ports are not published for the outside world. You can verify this with the following command:

```
 curl 127.0.0.1:50070
```

Comment: Thanks. So I actually misunderstood the scope of port exposure? I thought unless a port is exposed even the host OS would have no access to it?

Comment: The host only has access if you connect directly to the container IP, and that depends on iptables settings. Without exposing, you can't reach the container via a port on the host interface. In general, Docker isolates an application from the host, but not the host from the application.